# In a fragment implementation, the ListView below EditText disappears after setting keypad element (of EditText view) to hide

Tags: android, listview

[this is image while useing keypad](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CYdma.png)

[and this image after keypad was hidden](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CAdlA.png)

I use `EditText` but below it there is `ListView`. After typing text inputs in `EditText` and then press done or click back to hide keypad. Then the part of `ListView` behind the keypad disappeared and replaced by white area (cleared), why ?

NOTE: this fragment is under tablayout and viewpager and the fragment which contain the edit text and listview is launched from the main fragment
this is main fragment

```
    public class FriendsFragment extends Fragment {

public FriendsFragment() {
    // Required empty public constructor
}
private FragmentActivity myContext;

private Toolbar toolbar;
private TabLayout tabLayout;
private ViewPager viewPager;

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
}
@Override
public void onAttach(Activity activity) {
    myContext=(FragmentActivity) activity;
    super.onAttach(activity);
}
@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
   View rootview=inflater.inflate(R.layout.friends_fragment, container, false);


    viewPager = (ViewPager) rootview.findViewById(R.id.viewpager);
    setupViewPager(viewPager);

    tabLayout = (TabLayout) rootview.findViewById(R.id.tabs);
    tabLayout.setupWithViewPager(viewPager);

    tabLayout.setupWithViewPager(viewPager);

    tabLayout.setOnTabSelectedListener(
            new TabLayout.ViewPagerOnTabSelectedListener(viewPager) {
                @Override
                public void onTabSelected(TabLayout.Tab tab) {
                    super.onTabSelected(tab);

                    if (tab.getPosition() == 1) {
                        FindFriendsFragment.myfriends_list.invalidate(FindFriendsFragment.myfriends_list.getLeft(), FindFriendsFragment.myfriends_list.getTop(), FindFriendsFragment.myfriends_list.getRight(), FindFriendsFragment.myfriends_list.getBottom());
                        FindFriendsFragment.adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
                        FindFriendsFragment.myfriends_list.clearFocus();
                        FindFriendsFragment.myfriends_list.postInvalidate();
                    }


                }
            });





    TextView friends = (TextView) rootview.findViewById(R.id.search);
    Typeface Exo_thin = Typeface.createFromAsset(myContext.getAssets(), "fonts/Exo2.0-Thin.otf");
    friends.setTypeface(Exo_thin);
      return rootview;

 }
private void setupViewPager(ViewPager viewPager) {
    ViewPagerAdapter adapter = new ViewPagerAdapter(getChildFragmentManager());
     adapter.addFragment(new MyFriendsFragment(), "My Friends");
    adapter.addFragment(new FindFriendsFragment(), "Find Friends");
     adapter.addFragment(new TwoFragment(), "Friend Requests");
    viewPager.setAdapter(adapter);
}

class ViewPagerAdapter extends FragmentStatePagerAdapter {
    private final List<Fragment> mFragmentList = new ArrayList<>();
    private final List<String> mFragmentTitleList = new ArrayList<>();

    public ViewPagerAdapter(FragmentManager manager) {
        super(manager);
    }

    @Override
    public Fragment getItem(int position) {
        return mFragmentList.get(position);
    }

    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        return mFragmentList.size();
    }

    public void addFragment(Fragment fragment, String title) {
        mFragmentList.add(fragment);

        mFragmentTitleList.add(title);
    }

    @Override
    public CharSequence getPageTitle(int position) {
        return mFragmentTitleList.get(position);
    }
}
```

}

this is xml of main fragment

```
    <RelativeLayout
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
android:clickable="true"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
>


<android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
     android:textAllCaps="false"
    android:theme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark.ActionBar">
    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:id="@+id/rel"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"

        android:weightSum="1">

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="60dp"
            android:id="@+id/search"
            android:text="Friends"
            android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
            android:gravity="center_vertical"
            android:textSize="25sp"
             android:textColor="@color/colorVeryDarkBlue"
            />

    </RelativeLayout>


    <android.support.design.widget.TabLayout
        android:id="@+id/tabs"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        app:tabTextAppearance="@android:style/TextAppearance.Widget.TabWidget"
        app:tabSelectedTextColor="@color/colorLightGreen"
        app:tabTextColor="@color/colorDarkGreen"
         app:tabMode="scrollable"
         android:background="@color/colorDarkBlue"

        app:tabIndicatorColor="@color/colorDarkBlue"

        app:tabGravity="center"/>
</android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>

<android.support.v4.view.ViewPager
    android:id="@+id/viewpager"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior"/>
```

the fragment which contain listview and edit text

```
    public class FindFriendsFragment extends Fragment {

    public FindFriendsFragment()
    {
        // Required empty public constructor
    }
    ListView myfriends_list;
    FindFriendsAdapter adapter;
    ArrayList<FindFriends> arraylist ;


    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    }

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState)
    {
        View rootview= inflater.inflate(R.layout.find_friends_fragment, container, false);

      EditText search=(EditText) rootview.findViewById(R.id.search);

        Typeface Exo_Regular =   

         Typeface.createFromAsset(getActivity().getAssets(), "fonts/Exo2.0-
          Regular.otf");
        search.setTypeface(Exo_Regular);
        arraylist = new ArrayList<FindFriends>();
        arraylist.add(new FindFriends("mina fared", "hello     
            guys",1,"sdsdsdsds",true )) ;

        adapter = new FindFriendsAdapter(getActivity(), arraylist);

        myfriends_list.setAdapter(adapter);
        adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();


        return rootview;
    }

  }
```

And the related xml file is of the fragment which contain listview and edittext:

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
 android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:clickable="true"
android:background="#ffffff"
  >



<LinearLayout
    android:layout_height="60dp"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_marginTop="111dp"
    android:id="@+id/refl"
    android:background="@color/colorLightGrey"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    >

    <EditText
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="40dp"
         android:id="@+id/search"
        android:layout_marginRight="15dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="15dp"
        android:background="#ffffff"
        android:singleLine="true"
         android:hint="Search"
        android:ellipsize="start"
        android:imeOptions="actionDone"
        android:gravity="center_vertical|center_horizontal"
         android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
        android:textSize="15sp"
        android:textColorHint="@color/colormyhintfindfiernds"
        android:textColor="@color/colorDarkBlue"


        />

</LinearLayout>

<ListView
    android:id="@+id/listview"

    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
      android:background="#ffffff"
    android:layout_marginTop="1dp"
    android:layout_below="@+id/refl"
    android:divider="#ffffff"
    android:dividerHeight="1.5dp"
     />


   </RelativeLayout>
```

this is the parent fragment which contains all fragments

```
    public class ProfileFragment extends Fragment {

public ProfileFragment()
{
    // Required empty public constructor
}
RelativeLayout rl1;
DrawView drawView ;
DrawView  drawView2;
TextView myprofile,username,notification_txt,colloection_txt,friends_txt,setting_txt,public_profile_txt;
ImageView public_profile_btn,friends;
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
}

@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                         Bundle savedInstanceState)
{
   View rootview=inflater.inflate(R.layout.myprofile_fragment, container,   
   false);


    username= (TextView) rootview.findViewById(R.id.user_name_txt);
    myprofile= (TextView) rootview.findViewById(R.id.myprofile);
    notification_txt= (TextView) rootview.findViewById(R.id.notification_txt);
    colloection_txt= (TextView) rootview.findViewById(R.id.colloection_txt);
    friends_txt= (TextView) rootview.findViewById(R.id.friends_txt);
    setting_txt= (TextView) rootview.findViewById(R.id.setting_txt);
    public_profile_txt= (TextView) rootview.findViewById(R.id.public_profile_txt);


    Typeface Exo_thin = Typeface.createFromAsset(getActivity().getAssets(), "fonts/Exo2.0-Thin.otf");
    Typeface Exo_SemiBold = Typeface.createFromAsset(getActivity().getAssets(), "fonts/Exo2.0-SemiBold.otf");

    myprofile.setTypeface(Exo_thin);
    username.setTypeface(Exo_SemiBold);
    notification_txt.setTypeface(Exo_SemiBold);
    colloection_txt.setTypeface(Exo_SemiBold);
    friends_txt.setTypeface(Exo_SemiBold);
    setting_txt.setTypeface(Exo_SemiBold);
    public_profile_txt.setTypeface(Exo_SemiBold);
     ImageView x=(ImageView)rootview.findViewById(R.id.colloection);
    ImageView y=(ImageView)rootview.findViewById(R.id.friends);
    ImageView x1=(ImageView)rootview.findViewById(R.id.setting);
    rl1 =(RelativeLayout)rootview.findViewById(R.id.rel2);


   final View fragmentContainer = rootview.findViewById(R.id.container);

      friends  =(ImageView)rootview.findViewById(R.id.friends);
      public_profile_btn=(ImageView)rootview.findViewById(R.id.public_profile);
      public_profile_btn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view)
        {


            Fragment newFragment = new MyProfileFragment();
            FragmentTransaction transaction = getFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
            transaction.replace(fragmentContainer.getId(), newFragment);

             transaction.addToBackStack(null);
            transaction.commit();

        }
    });

    friends.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view)
        {


            Fragment newFragment = new FriendsFragment();
            FragmentTransaction transaction = getFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
            transaction.replace(fragmentContainer.getId(), newFragment);

            transaction.addToBackStack(null);
            transaction.commit();

        }
    });

     return rootview;
  }
```

}

Comment: try calling `listView.postInvalidate()` in the method in which you hide the keyboard. I suspect it's just a matter of view's cache getting a little stale.

Comment: Try to `listview.requestFocus();`

Comment: this is all code in the fargment and its xml @piyush

Comment: i hide keyboard by click done or press back i don't use any method to hide it @Shark

Comment: @MinaFared then override `onBackPressed()` and do `super.onBackPressed(); listView.invalidate();` if that doesn't do it, then try the alternative - `listView.invalidate(listView.getLeft(), listView.getTop(), listView.getRight(), listView.getBottom());`

Comment: final View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.find_friends_fragment, null, false).Use this for inflating and try

Comment: sorry i used your answer  but problem is not solved :( @Shark

Comment: sorry i used your answers  but problem is not solved :( @piyush

Comment: sorry i used your answers  but problem is not solved :( @Kristo1990

Comment: NOTE: this fragment is under tablayout and viewpager

Comment: Then your problem is a bit more complicated (less trivial) than I first suspected, and you may have to post some more code to reveal it.

Comment: i post the full code @Shark thx in advance :)

Comment: Where is the fragment's parent `Activity` code? :)

Comment: the parent is a fragment  not activity , i posted its code @Shark

Answer (score 1, accepted):

from manifest.xml search for your activity tag like this

```
<activity
        android:name=".YourActivity"
        android:label="@string/title_activity"
        ...>
</activity>
```

then add android:configChanges="keyboard|keyboardHidden" like that

```
<activity
        android:name=".YourActivity"
        android:configChanges="keyboard|keyboardHidden"
        android:label="@string/title_activity"
        ...>
</activity>
```

**EDIT**

i found that my answer not completely right you may add

```
android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustNothing"
```

sorry about that

Comment: my answer is wrong i don`t know how that happened. any way 
you may add this instead  android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustNothing"